# Visual Studio Project templates

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, templates, project

I would like to create a custom project template in visual studio 2010/2008 and I am looking for any resources/information that we give me a good starting point. Furthermore, I need to be able to create custom folders in those projects. Has anyone had any experience with that?

**EDIT:**
I found some more information on the matter and I am trying to sum up my findings and draw some conclusions. From the answer below I saw one approach of creating project templates

Another approach I found: [here](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=170)

which uses the vs SDK and exposes a new project template called "Project template". 
I saw some other things like GAX/GAT and Starter kits. 
Does anyone have some experience with any of those approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read an extensive information about project templates on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They describe everything in details. Also, there is an information how to create custom project templates. It should be enough for the start. As for the second approach, where SDK is used, you can find the difference and guides on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527340.aspx) as well. There is also information about Starter kits.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Seems that the information there is pretty extensive. However, I also saw another post that accomplishes this by installing the vs SDK and creating a new "project template" project. Here is the link http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=170 . Do you know anything about this, what is the difference for example between the two approaches?

Comment: Guide that you link describes how to create ItemTemplates (what you can add to your existing project by Right Mouse Button->Add new item). I gave you link to general info where can you find also how to create Project Templates (what you select when creating new project).